# CNContactViewController button action

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, contacts

I am using `CNContactViewController`. But, I want to add a new button. How to I do

If you can not add a new button then how can I get the action of the Call button?

[image]

Comment: Where you need put your button?

Comment: Above the buttons message, call,video,mail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you try like this but i have used for new contact and you can customize with you code.

```
func CreateNewContact() {

    let contact = CNMutableContact()


    let unkvc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact)
    unkvc.delegate = self
    unkvc.allowsEditing = true
    unkvc.allowsActions = true
    unkvc.title = "Create New Contact"
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 234.0/255.0, green: 34.0/255.0, blue: 39.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    Application.Delegate.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor(red: 198/255.0, green: 6/255.0, blue: 39.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0))


    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    let rightButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(ShowInfotoshare.doneButtonClicked(_:)))

    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton


    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(unkvc, animated: false)



}

func doneButtonClicked(_ button:UIBarButtonItem!){
    print("Done clicked")
}
```

If you have any query then show me your code so i will help you.

Comment: That didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the row of buttons under the name (lets call them "methods of communications") cannot be modified. You can't hide the row, or individual buttons, you can't add anything into the row.

Also, the buttons active/inactive state is controlled by the current contact information (that is displayed below it).

Finally, note that the simulator, because it doesn't present a phone calling service nor include Mail.app, the buttons status will be pretty different from a real device.